# Angular js to angular 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am writing an Angular application and I have an old code i want to convert this angular js code to angular

**table.html**

```
<table ng-repeat="group in vm.groups" style="float: left">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><b>Sl. No</b></th>
          <th><b>Generated Code</b></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="g in group.values">
        <td ng-style="$odd ? {'background': 'lightgrey' } : {'background': 'white' }">{{$parent.$index * 10 + $index +  1}}</td>
        <td ng-style="$odd ? {'background': 'lightgrey' } : {'background': 'white' }">{{g.value}}</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

**table.ts**

```
 app.controller('Ctrl', function() {
      var vm = this;

      var items = [{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'},{value: 'bbb'}];
      vm.groups = [];
      var i,j,temparray,chunk = 10;
      for (i=0,j=items.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        temparray = items.slice(i,i+chunk);
        vm.groups.push({values: temparray});
      }
    });
```

i Want to convert this code to Angular2+. I am new to angular please help me.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQ1NpOa96IpzSncbFSud?p=preview&preview  this is the source

Comment: please help to convert this code in angular 2+

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? At the moment, your question is akin to "here's my code, I want to do this with it - do it for me". You need to show what you have already tried and any specific problems you're having, otherwise your question could be flagged as too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2 onwards you should use `*ngFor` directive to loop over array.

so , your `component.html` should look like below :

```
<table *ngFor="let group of groups; let i=index">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Sl. No</b></th>
            <th><b>Generated Code</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let g of group.values; let x=index" [ngClass]="(x%2===0)?'even':'odd'">
        <td>{{i * 10 + x +  1}}</td>
        <td>{{g.value}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Below is the Angular 8 conversion of your code : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwqxww)